# WPF Не удается найти ресурс

Tags: wpf, xaml

Код в App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="APP.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:APP"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Data/Theme/Light.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Добавил *`Data/Theme/Light.xaml`* в ресурсы.
Запускаю, и ошибки:

- Необработанное исключение типа "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException" в PresentationFramework.dll
- "Задание свойства "System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source" вызвало исключение.": номер строки "9" и позиция в строке "18"

Как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Относительные URI в разметке начинаются со слеша, см. Таблицу 2 в документации [Programming with Pack URIs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#programming-with-pack-uris):

> Resource file in subfolder of local assembly — `"/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml"`